# How to use Pingendo 4 with themes and templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pingendo

I'm using Pingendo V4 (not-beta).

I assume templates are partly completed pages that I can start with and modify, and that Themes are only selections of shapes, colors that I can use on my own pages. Is that correct?

Can I download a (I assume Bootstrap) theme or template, use it locally and then transfer the files to my web site? How is the download done and them integrated with Pingendo?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are completed pages that you can edit and customize to your liking. Themes are sets of customizations. Sometimes themes and templates are made for particular business types, for example pingendo has a app, resteraunt, and fasion templates complete with there coresponding themes. With Pingendo you can download your theme by doing the following: Go to the HTML tab, which gives you the HTML view of your page. Copy and paste that into your own index.html page. Secondly go to the sass view in Pingendo and copy and past it into a custom.sass file that you create. Keep in mind you will want to convert that sass to css, there are free tools that do this online. Depending on your webhost the method of putting them online will be different. Most of the time you will need to FTP your files on to the server, put your html into the main folder may be names something like public_html. Put your css into a folder in the main folder called css, make sure your link to the css in your index.html reflects the file path. Once you have it downloaded there is no need to reintegrate it into Pingendo, the only time you will need to go back there is if you need to make changes. Of course you could always hand code the changes as well.

Comment: I think you have jumped a few steps. What am I supposed to download and from where - a theme? a template? Can you point me to an example that I can download? Let's start there.    No need to cover FTPing to a server. I know how to do that.

Comment: I'm still confused. I agree with your distinction between Themes and Templates, but online offerings are only Templates. They may be called Themes, but they are really templates. You download them, rename the main page "index.html", and then modify them. I would have thought that a Theme would be a collection of css, js, etc files without any html files at all. give me a url to an actual online Theme rather than a Template.

Comment: Found a few. Let's try using the Cerulean theme at Bootswatch.com. Start Pingendo and use a blank page as the first page. What do you do them to use that theme?

Comment: I can continue to help, but first you need to mark the previous threads as answered as I mentioned in a previous comment. So that this discussion does not just benift you, but the community as well. If I did not answer those questions to your liking then, we should have continued our discussion there.

Comment: OK, on marking as "Answered" once I figure out how.
I tried the Cerulean theme from Bootswatch and it worked. All I needed to do was download the CSS file and in Pingendo  use menu Theme > Load from disk. I managed to change between themes just by loading a new CSS file. This part is solved.

Comment: Well mark your previous questions as solved if those particular issue have been resolved, if they were not then a new post should not have been made.

Comment: So what is left to resolve with your issue? I can try to step you through it, without starting a new thread.

Comment: I have also downloaded a Bootstrap template and used it successfully. Frankly, unless a template has very much what you're looking for its best to start with something very basic and add your own. Themes are much more useful in that way. I have nothing more to ask except where to submit documentation for Pingendo? Stack Overflow is great, but it would be a shame to spend time on this and then not contribute more directly to those looking at Pingendo.

Comment: Documentation is currently in beta, but you can start doing some documenting there if you want. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pingendo/info